# How to update Odoo Custom Module's Model

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-10

I have a custom module with a model installed, i want to update the module as i have made change in design of the module. Is there anyway to update the model structure like removing or deleting field in the model in ODOO v10.

Comment: which IDE are you using? Eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

I had a little experience with odoo 8, as I know once you add a field to a model you can't simply remove it, because it passes throught the ORM to the SGBD, so if you remove it from the model it will remain in the table of the database. maybe you can try to remove the table from the data base and re execute your code **(I used to do that on a test database I DON'T recommend to do so on a database with real data)**. If it doesn't work, I think you should create a new database, and install your module after you make your changes on the model.

Comment: is that means that once a model gets deployed it can never be updated

Comment: I think that u can't remove an existing field but you can add a new field, you can try it yourself ;)   . I made a search on internet, and I believe that this link https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/delete-fields-from-database-without-uninstall-89352 can help answer you, read all comments and the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Surely you can do it via logging in with 'admin' credentials.

Navigate to 'Settings' menu and activate 'Developers Mode' through the link given at the right corner in the 'Dashboard' page:

[image: Settings -> Dashboard]

After activating the Developer Mode, you will be able to see menu item named: 'Technical -> Database Structure -> Models'

[image: Settings -> Database Structure -> Models]

You can select your model and update the fields for it. You can add, remove, edit any field of the model.

**Note: These changes will effect your database structure, so I would advice you to first take a backup of your current database and then apply the changes.**

Thanks

Comment: I can do addition of fields but i cannot delete a field

Comment: The fields whose type is 'Base' cannot be deleted.

Comment: If you are creating the field from UI, then only the **Type** of the field is **Custom Field** and then the application allows you to delete the field.